# NuxtJs: ReferenceError: NuxtError is not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am new to NuxtJs. I wanted to test how nuxt-link works so I intentionally put a nuxt-link to a route that doesn't work hoping to get redirected to the default 404 page. I put this line the `pages/index.vue` file:

```
<nuxt-link to='/asksdkjd'>ssss</nuxt-link>
```

And it displays in chrome like [this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5aPI.png)

After I click the link I get these error in console:

```
ReferenceError: NuxtError is not defined
at Vue.errorChanged (App.js?efe7:173)
at Watcher.run (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4568)
at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4310)
at Array.eval (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1980)
at flushCallbacks (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1906)

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in watcher with expression "nuxt.err"
(found in <Root>)
```

Here's the [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNjp9.png)
This error shows when I am redirected to the link because you can see the invalid link in the url bar. It doesn't render the default 404 page.
But When I hit refresh, I can then see the 404 page[(sceenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2p4K.png).

Here's my `nuxt.config.js` file which was generated when I installed this fresh project.(I ommited the comments.)

```
export default {
  mode: 'universal',
  target: 'static',
  head: {
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  css: [
  ],
  plugins: [
  ],
  components: true,
  buildModules: [
  ],
  modules: [
  ],
  build: {
  }
}
```

I have been googling for this error for quite a while but couldn't find anything. I also tried in firefox but the same issue is happening. Hope you guys can help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like this bug was introduced in the framework with a Pull Request. A contributer already requested a PR to fix the issue. Here's the [link](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8066) of the issue I created.

Answer (score 1):

define your error page.

create this file: layouts/error.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div v-if="error.statusCode === 404">
      <h1>Page not found</h1>
      <p>{{ error.message }}</p>
    </div>
    <div v-else>
      <h1>An error occurred</h1>
    </div>
    <n-link to="/">Home page</n-link>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['error'],
  layout: 'default' // If you prefers you can set a custom layout for the error page
}
</script>
```

More info: check the nuxt docs about [error page](https://nuxtjs.org/guides/directory-structure/layouts#error-page)

Comment: Thanks but that is a custom error page that I can create. I was trying to get redirected to the default 404 page. Anyway as it turned out that there is bug with the current version of nuxt.js. I hope it get's fixed soon. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: There is a missing closing </p> before error.message.